# Why doesnt fixed position work as i expected when a fixed div is a child of a fixed child?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, css-position

My goal is to open side tabs and have them "recursively" open. I made a component in vue and logically it seemed to work fine. But in practice I find that each open form becomes smaller and smaller because for some reason the "fixed" children consider the point (0,0) as the parent form and not the viewport.

Initially I thought it might be a vue virtualization issue (?), but I skimmed my code as much as I could but the problem remained the same.

Here is the sample code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="">
      <!-- a hypothetical parent tab (1 "tab" component) -->
      <div class="fixed top-0 right-0 left-0 bottom-0" id="component1">
        <p>Component1 start</p>
        <div class="fixed z-20 top-0 right-0 left-0 bottom-0" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);"></div>
        <div class="fixed z-20 top-0 right-0 h-full w-1/4">
          <div class="h-full w-full flex flex-col transform transition-transform bg-yellow-500">

            <!-- a hypothetical child tab (2 "tab" component) -->
            <div class="fixed top-0 right-0 left-0 bottom-0" id="component2">
              <p>Component2 start</p>
              <div class="fixed z-20 top-0 right-0 left-0 bottom-0" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);"></div>
              <div class="fixed z-20 top-0 right-0 h-full w-1/4">
                <div class="h-full w-full flex flex-col transform transition-transform bg-orange-500">

                  <div class="">
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I expect the orange tab to overlap the yellow tab. (The yellow tab becomes ocher, because the opacity that I apply to the left of the orange tab, instead of considering the viewport, considers the component1 tab body).

More than a patch, because it could be "solved" by putting a fixed size on the tab and therefore the recursive ones will not have opacity on the side (the least of the problems), I would like to understand why this approach isn't working.

Comment: You can read up about 'containing block' at file:///C:/Users/annet/Documents/test10.html In particular, in your case (position: fixed) the system will take the nearest ancestor that has a transform property set.

Comment: Damn. I knew I was missing something. Thanks a lot for the clarification!
I'll have to come up with something else to make these tabs work

Comment: Sorry, I gave the wrong link above. Should be https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block# For finding out about fixed and containing block.

Comment: oh yes, I figured no prob!.  i went to the documentation and looking for transform it was one of the points between the exceptions in the behavior of the fixed